# Override Methods in C/C++ like Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi

In Delphi we have an option to do a thing like this:

```
TClass1 = class
  procedure Test; virtual;
end;

TClass2 = class(TClass1)
  procedure Test; override;
end;
```

So in code, If I create an instance of TClass2, even if I cast the object like:

```
TClass1(ObjectClass2).Test;
```

The application will call the function declared on TClass2.

But in C/C++ I could not find a way to do this.

If I declare some void as virtual and implement the same void in the children class when I do the cast to the parent class it'll not use the implementation of the children class.

Does anyone know how I can reproduce the behavior of Delphi in C/C++ ?

---

New informations:
These are my files.

```
---------------------- File Filho.hpp
#ifndef FILHO_HPP
#define FILHO_HPP
#include "Pai.hpp"

class Filho : public Pai {
public:
    Filho();
    virtual ~Filho();
    void metodoX();
};

Filho::Filho() {}
Filho::~Filho() {}

void Filho::metodoX() {
    std::cout << "Hello Filho!" << std::endl;
}
#endif


---------------------- File Pai.hpp
#ifndef PAI_HPP
#define PAI_HPP
#include <iostream>

class Pai {
public:
    Pai();
    virtual ~Pai();
    virtual void metodoX();
};
Pai::Pai() {}
Pai::~Pai() {}

void Pai::metodoX() {
    std::cout << "Hello Pai!" << std::endl;
}

#endif

---------------------- File Main.hpp
#include "Pai.hpp"
#include "Filho.hpp"

int main() {
    Pai pai;
    pai.metodoX();      //Here output the msg Hello Pai!

    Filho filho;           
    filho.metodoX();    //Here output the msg Hello Filho!

    ((Pai) filho).metodoX(); //Here output the msg Hello Pai! , but here if I use the directive 'override' in Delphi, the output will be Hello Filho!. Here is my doubt.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you describe should work. Show us your c++ code.

Comment: I'll use my lunch time to post my code and verify the answers, tks in advice

Comment: @saCi The difference is that you are creating stack-based objects. If you create the object on the heap, as per my answer and that of birryree then it will behave as Delphi does, and as you desire.

Comment: Tks David Haffernan, I understood the difference. 
I'll accept the birryree answer 'cause he post first. 
But tks to you to your explanation and patience.

Comment: @SaCi Actually, I posted first, but the post with the most votes appears first! But it's fine, birryeee gave you lots of C++ detail which I am hazy on - I think he deserves the accept. I know Delphi very well, so between us I think we've given you good help.

Comment: @Saci - I see that you updated with your code that does this: `((Pai)filho).metodoX();`. So when you do that, you are not using pointers/references to a base class. You are just casting the `filho` object to a `Pai` object. This does not result in a polymorphic function call, and instead will just call the `Pai::metodoX()` function. If you did this instead: `((Pai*)filho)->metodoX();`, it would call `Filho`'s `metodoX()` polymorphically. I've updated my answer with this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not a Delphi expert, but I can explain how this stuff behaves in C++.

So in C++, you can have a class that defines a `virtual` function, which means that if you use a base class pointer/reference to an object, that function can be invoked via dynamic dispatch (i.e. runtime function lookup).

```
#include <iostream>

class BaseClass
{
public:
    virtual void virtFunc() { std::cout << "BaseClass\n"; } // notice the 'virtual' keyword
    void nonvirtFunc() { std::cout << "BaseClass\n"; }
};


class SubClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
   virtual void virtFunc() { std::cout << "SubClass\n"; }
   void nonvirtFunc() { std::cout << "SubClass\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    // You need to use base class pointers/references
    SubClass sc = SubClass();
    BaseClass *bcp = &sc;
    bcp->virtFunc(); // prints "SubClass"     
    bcp->nonvirtFunc(); // prints "BaseClass"   

    // doing it by allocating an object on heap
    BaseClass *dbcp = new SubClass();
    dbcp->virtFunc(); // prints "SubClass"
    dbcp->nonvirtFunc(); // prints "BaseClass"
    delete dbcp; // in a real program, you should have a virtual destructor which will be called from this code

    BaseClass bc = SubClass();
    bc.virtFunc(); // prints "BaseClass", and in more complex objects, slicing occurs
}
```

---

#### New Code You Posted

I see that you updated with your code that does this:

```
((Pai)filho).metodoX();
```

So when you do that, you are not using pointers/references to a base class. You are just casting the `filho` object to a `Pai` object. This does not result in a polymorphic function call, and instead will just call the `Pai::metodoX()` function.

If you did this instead:

```
((Pai*)filho)->metodoX();
```

It would call `Filho`'s `metodoX()` polymorphically.

Comment: +1 Delphi only has heap allocated reference objects, like Java and C#. I'm guessing that OP's problem is due to the use of a stack-based object. You've made all this very clear in your answer.

Comment: @David - Thanks for letting me know, I didn't know that about Delphi.

Answer (score 6):

In C++ you would write:

```
class Class1
{
  public:
    virtual void Test();
};

class Class2: public Class1
{
  public:
    virtual void Test();
};

Class1* obj = new Class2();
obj->Test();//calls Class2.Test()
```

This achieves the same as your Delphi example.

The key is to create the C++ object on the heap and maintain a reference to it, which is of course the only way to do things in Delphi which does not support stack based objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
TClass1* obj = new TClass2 ;
obj->procedure();
```

If, `TClass1` ( base class) and `TClass2` ( derived class ) has hierarchial relationships( i.e., inheritance )

```
class TClass1
{
    public:
    virtual void procedure(){} // Assuming procedure's return type is void.
    virtual ~TClass1(){}
};

class TClass2 : public TClass1
{
    public:
    void procedure(){}
};
```